# Firefox undocumented options

Tags: firefox

I came across Firefox
[**undocumented options**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)

```
-print-xpcom-dir
-print-xpcom-dirlist
-kill
-killAll
-f
-ftimeout
-fwait
-unsetDefaultMail
-foreground
-new-instance
GTK options
```

Perhaps someone "in the know" can comment on these or link to a reference? I tried for example `firefox -kill` and `firefox -killAll` but they seem to do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first two exist in the source code. In fact they are sort of mummies, only read and not applied anywhere.